# Four cards are randomly chosen without replacement from an ordinary deck of 52 playing cards.

Tags: probability, card-games

Four cards are randomly chosen without replacement from an ordinary deck of 52 playing cards. What is the chance of all chosen cards **not** being aces?

I found a similar problem [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2854807/three-cards-are-randomly-chosen-without-replacement-from-an-ordinary-deck-of-52) but the provided answer doesn't help me.
So, all the card that aren't aces are 48.
But I don't know if all cases are 52 or $^{52}C_4$.
Therefore, I am wondering if the probability is $P(A)=\frac{48}{52}$ or $P(A)=\frac{48}{^{52}C_4}$. 
The second probability should be the right one but it looks too low to be realistic. Which is the right answer?

Comment: @Aatmaj: Thanks for adding the [tag:card-games] tag. I reverted your edit to the title. Please don't add generic terms like "question" to titles. All posts on this site are questions – imagine how the main page would look and how inefficient it would be if all questions had titles like that. Tag names, likewise, shouldn't be in the title. The tags are for broad categorizations; the title is for summarizing the specific question.

Comment: thanks I will remember that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are $52$ cards in total, but you can effectively only pick from $48$ of them (the non-aces).

This gives the probability as:

$$\frac{\binom{48}{4}}{\binom{52}{4}}$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer!